# how to copy one field input value to other field input using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

want to copy some fields from my form to another field when someone click checkbox and remove when uncheck box.

how i did it, but its not working.

```
<script>
function filladdress(f) {
  if(f.sameaddress.checked == true) {
    f.present_address1.value = f.perm_address1.value;
    f.present_address2.value = f.perm_address2.value;
    f.present_address3.value = f.perm_address3.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

here is the form goes..

```
<form name="OnlineForm" method="post" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" action="apply4.php">
<input name="present_address1" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address1" value="" size="43"  maxlength="35">
<input name="present_address2" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address2" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
<input name="present_address3" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address3" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">

<input type="checkbox" name="sameaddress" onclick="filladdress(this.OnlineForm)">

<input name="perm_address1" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address1" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
<input name="perm_address2" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address2" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
<input name="perm_address3" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address3" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit long code as I have selected each fields thus you can understand it much better, every-time when user click `checkbox` it store the value in `variable` individually for each `input[name='present_address1']` and replaces in `input[name='perm_address1']`.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").onclick = function(){
 var val1 = document.querySelector("input[name='present_address1']").value;
  var val2 = document.querySelector("input[name='present_address2']").value;
 var val3 = document.querySelector("input[name='present_address3']").value;
 if(this.checked){
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address1']").value = val1;
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address2']").value = val2;
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address3']").value = val3;
  }
  else{
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address1']").value = "";
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address2']").value = "";
   document.querySelector("input[name='perm_address3']").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="OnlineForm" method="post" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" action="apply4.php">
  <input name="present_address1" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address1" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
  <input name="present_address2" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address2" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
  <input name="present_address3" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="present_address3" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">

  <input type="checkbox" name="sameaddress">

  <input name="perm_address1" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address1" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
  <input name="perm_address2" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address2" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
  <input name="perm_address3" type="text" title="Maximum 35 Character allowed" class="textBoxDashed" id="perm_address3" value="" size="43" maxlength="35">
```

Comment: it is working fine here in codesnippet, but on my page its not working.

Comment: thanks man ! its working now, i was loading javascript at wrong places, thats why it was not working..

Comment: Welcome :-) Glad that worked after including script at right place.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document` instead `this` in html when checkbox click

you will get undefined pass by `this.OnlineForm`

see here demo https://jsbin.com/subebaz/edit?html,js,output

and also switch your value assignment sequence in copy function

Comment: your demo working fine in codesnippet, but i dont know why your demo not working on my page.

Comment: it is working fine now, i was loading js at wrong place. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<script>
    function filladdress(f) {
        if(document.forms['f']['present_address1'].checked == true) {
            document.forms['f']['present_address1'].value = document.forms['f']['perm_address1'].value;
            document.forms['f']['present_address2'].value = document.forms['f']['perm_address2'].value;
            document.forms['f']['present_address3'].value = document.forms['f']['perm_address3'].value;
        }
    }
</script>
```